# ionic 3 navegar por paginas enviando parametro href

Tags: ionic3

En angular para redirigir a otra pagina se usaba

```
<a [routerLink]="['/editar-producto',producto.id]"  class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a>
```

Pero en ionic cual es la forma? Como se debe colocar en app.component.ts para recibir estos parametros?

```
this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
      { title: 'List', component: ListPage },
      { title: 'Productos', component: ProductsPage },
      { title: 'Agregar producto', component: CreateProductPage }
    ];
```

pero para recibir parametros?

En angular4 la configuracion era

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

//Componentes
import {HomeComponent} from './components/home.component';
import {ErrorComponent} from './components/error.component';
import {ProductosComponent} from './components/productos.component';
import { ProductoAddComponent } from './components/producto-add.component'
import {ProductoDetailComponent} from './components/producto-detalle.component';
import {ProductoEditComponent} from './components/producto-edit.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'productos', component: ProductosComponent},
    {path: 'crear-producto', component: ProductoAddComponent},
    {path: 'producto/:id', component: ProductoDetailComponent},
    {path: 'editar-producto/:id', component: ProductoEditComponent},
    {path: '**', component: ErrorComponent}
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Pero en ionic no tengo nada de esto

```
{path: 'editar-producto/:id', component: ProductoEditComponent},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya descubri como en el componente productos se debe colocar un metodo llamado

```
editProduct(id) {
    this.navCtrl.push(ProductEditPage, {
      idProduct: id,
    })
  }
```

luego eso quiere decir que ProductEditPage recibira un parametro get llamado idProduct.

Despues en product-edit se realiza

`public idProduct;` declarando atributo

y luego en el constructor

```
this.idProduct = navParams.get("idProduct");
```

Ya con eso tengo el id por href. Agregando en la vista de productos

Ya que en ionic no se usa get url por estar orientado a mobiles.